# overloaded method match for NAudio.Wave.IWavePlayer.Init

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to play sounds in my .net project using code from link below
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with.html
and getting this error-

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'NAudio.Wave.IWavePlayer.Init(NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider)' has some invalid arguments   D:\marathiTyping\Marathi Typing\Marathi Typing\AudioPlaybackEngine.cs   26  9   Marathi Typing

Error   2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders.MixingSampleProvider' to 'NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider' D:\marathiTyping\Marathi Typing\Marathi Typing\AudioPlaybackEngine.cs   27  27  Marathi Typing
The code looks like-

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;

public int sampleRate, channelCount;

public AudioPlaybackEngine()
  {
    sampleRate = 44100;
    channelCount = 2;
    outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
    mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channelCount));
    mixer.ReadFully = true;
    outputDevice.Init(mixer);
    outputDevice.Play();
  }

public AudioPlaybackEngine(int sRate, int cCount)
  {
    sampleRate = sRate;
    channelCount = cCount;
    outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
    mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channelCount));
    mixer.ReadFully = true;
    outputDevice.Init(mixer);
    outputDevice.Play();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `Init` you want is an extension method in the `NAudio.Wave` namespace allowing you to pass in an `ISampleProvider` instead of an `IWaveProvider`. If the code doesn't compile, maybe you are using an old version of NAudio.